# Jenkins Plugin Install Failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows

I am trying to set up new Jenkins. When I download Suggested Plugins OR try to install any plugin I am getting below error. 
I am using Jenkins Latest **Version 2.204.1**. I have set up this on **VM**. I am getting this error for all the plugins even when I am trying to install suggested plugins during the initial setup, that time also I am getting the same error. I am installing Jenkins on Microsoft Windows Server VM. I have downloaded Jenkins from Browser, extracted zip file and installed it using jenkins.msi.

````
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1194)
Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)```[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TgUP.png
````

Comment: It was most likely a site issue w/[http://jenkins.io](http://jenkins.io); see now resolved [INFRA-2393](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/INFRA/issues/INFRA-2393)

Answer (score 1):

You can try 3 different things-

1. Try pinging https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/ and see if it gets any response. If it doesn't respond then make sure your internet is working fine.
2. You can try installing the plugins by connecting to a VPN.
3. Lastly, you can reinstall Jenkins to see if the error persists.

Comment: It was most likely a site issue w/[http://jenkins.io](http://jenkins.io); see now resolved [INFRA-2393](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/INFRA/issues/INFRA-2393)

Answer (score 0):

I have to reinstall the Jenkins 2-3 time and it starts working, but at an initial level still, I am not able to install suggested plugins. I have setup Jenkins first and then installed all the plugins manually.